# Neural Network Regression Experiment Going Wrong

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I've been trying to get a simple regression experiment going with a neural network and I would like some help interpreting what is going wrong.

My goal is to see what level of regression accuracy I can achieve with a feed forward neural network. I have N pairs of inputs, x, and outputs, y.

As an example:

```
X is made up of serial integers starting at 0: e.x [0 1 2 3 ... N]
Y is made up of pairs of random floats between 0 and 1: e.x [[.263 .548] [.157 .014] [.988 .478] ... Nth [.356 .245]].
```

So my neural network's structure has 1 input neuron and 2 output neurons and some hidden layers in between whose properties are part of this experiment.

These are the questions I seek to answer:

1. Can this neural network with some configuration of hidden layers map these inputs and outputs with perfect accuracy?
2. If not, what is the best accuracy that can be achieved with a reasonably sized network?
3. Is there a limit on the value of N such that the accuracy of the mapping deteriorates past an accuracy threshold t for each value a and b of an output pair, [a, b], of +- z where z is fairly small? In other words can the prediction z stay withing a - t and a + t
   and the same for b?

Here is my model and some relevant functions as it stands:

```
# Custom Loss
def absoluteDifference(y_true, y_pred):
  return abs(y_pred - y_true)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu', input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(magnitudes))

model.compile(loss=absoluteDifference, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The results of my experiments are confusing. It always seems to bottom out at some accuracy threshold and never progress. When I compare the outputs of the network to the y value pairs they are either  wildly different than y or the predictions seem to be flattening at one value:

Here are some actual results:

```
Results 1: Flattening:
Y:     
[[0.2890625  0.43554688]
 [0.1171875  0.02734375]
 [0.44921875 0.11328125]
 [0.04296875 0.25585938]
 [0.4921875  0.42578125]
 [0.09960938 0.04101562]
 [0.265625   0.05273438]
 [0.421875   0.26757812]
 [0.40625    0.0859375 ]
 [0.25976562 0.1328125 ]]

Predictions:
[[0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]
 [0.27030337 0.11708295]]

Results 2: Different:
Y:
[[0.3515625  0.47851562]
 [0.16796875 0.28320312]
 [0.140625   0.453125  ]
 [0.21679688 0.44726562]
 [0.21484375 0.0859375 ]
 [0.47265625 0.15429688]
 [0.37304688 0.30078125]
 [0.06054688 0.04492188]
 [0.49609375 0.41992188]
 [0.4453125  0.40820312]]

Predictions:
[[0.18319808 0.33377975]
 [0.16718353 0.33032405]
 [0.19876595 0.32554907]
 [0.23596771 0.3200497 ]
 [0.2726316  0.31566542]
 [0.30836326 0.31124872]
 [0.34609824 0.30569595]
 [0.38202912 0.30291694]
 [0.4184485  0.2967524 ]
 [0.45500547 0.29231113]]
```

I would have expected Y and Predictions to match after training. What am I doing wrong here?